# Programming a battleships ship placing algorithm(java)

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm

So im programming a battleships game, and im trying to place ships on a board. I can get it to place the ship going left and going down from the starting point but cant get it going down or left. I understand my method overall is in-effeicient.

```
public static int[][] SetUserBoard(int[][] board) {

    int x;
    int y;

    y = 0;

    for (int z = 0; z < 10; z++) {
        String gridv;
        gridv = "";

        int direction;

        System.out.println("Set the Position for Ship no. " + (z+1));

        Scanner s1 = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter the grid column(A-H):");

        gridv = s1.nextLine();


        if (gridv.equals("A")) {
            y = 0;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("B")) {
            y = 1;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("C")) {
            y = 2;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("D")) {
            y = 3;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("E")) {
            y = 4;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("F")) {
            y = 5;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("G")) {
            y = 6;
        }
        if (gridv.equals("H")) {
            y = 7;
        }


        System.out.println("Enter the y co=ordinate: ");
        x = s1.nextInt();
        x -= 1;

        System.out.println("Enter the direction of the ship 0-3(0=down,1=right,2=up,3=left): ");
        direction = s1.nextInt();

        if(z == 0) {    //placing 4 unit ship in first increment
            if(direction == 0 && x < 5){ //vertical placement - down
                for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                    board[x][y] = 0;
                    x += 1;
                }
            }
            if(direction == 1 && y < 5) { //horizontal placement - right
                for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                    board[x][y] = 0;
                    y += 1;
                }
            }
            if(direction == 2 && x > 3 ) {  //vertical placement - up
                for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                    board[x][y] = 0;
                    x -= 1;
                }
            }
            if(direction == 3 && y > 3) {   //horizontal placement - left
                for(int i=0; i < 4; i++) {
                    board[x][y] = 0;
                    y -= 1;
                }
            }
        }
        ...if(z > 0 && z < 3) { //placing 3 unit ships in 2nd and 3rd increment....

    return board;


}
```

if you ignore the bottom part, and focus on the if z=0 part as that's which part i'm using to test this with my most updated try. Originally I had an indexing error which I managed to solve but now all the program does is run as usual except when moving onto the next one the board isn't updated and is still empty. So im stumped as to what logic to use for up/left.

Comment: Do you have some output showing the problem?  Supply a main program and some print statements to exhibit the problem.

Comment: It seems unusual that you'd be setting `board[x][y]=0` to represent a ship placement.  Could it be a zero-value is already being used to represent a blank coordinate?

Answer (score 0):

For diagonal changes, you need to alter *both* `i` and `j` as you traverse the ship.  For instance:

```
UP_LEFT = 4
...
ship_len = 4
...

        if(direction == UP_LEFT && 
           y > ship_len-1 &&
           x > ship_len-1) {   // SE-NW placement
            for(int i=0; i < ship_len; i++) {
                board[x][y] = 0;
                y -= 1;
                x -= 1;
            }
        }
```

Comment: apologies i was vague in my comment. but i dont need diagonal changes. the issue im having is getting it to go up or left